# The differences between MySQLdb and mysqlconnector

Tags: python, mysql

there are two methods to connect mysql using python,

1

```
import mysql.connector
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger',host='127.0.0.1',database='employees')
    cnx.close()
```

2

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="john", # your username
                      passwd="megajonhy", # your password
                      db="jonhydb") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")
```

I do not know the differences between MySQLdb and mysql connector,when should I use MySQLdb and when should I use mysql connector? Please tell me ,thanks very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQLdb is a C module that links against the MySQL protocol implementation in the libmysqlclient library. It is faster, but requires the library in order to work.

mysql-connector is a Python module that reimplements the MySQL protocol in Python. It is slower, but does not require the C library and so is more portable.